# How To Make This Matrix in Python

Tags: python

I have this code.  Everything works fine.

```
    P = np.matrix(' \
                  1 0.5 0.5 0.5  \
                  ')          
    print( P )
```

The output is [[1.  0.5 0.5 0.5]]

I want to make the same matrix without using a string.  So I tried

```
    P = [[ 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 ]]

    print( P )
```

The output is slightly different.  It is

```
    [[1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]]
```

The second version does not suit my purpose.  The following code works with the first version but not the second.

```
p = (P - 1/2)* 2 * scale()

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float'
```

So...how do I get the first version of the matrix without making it from a string?

Answer (score 0):

Same matrix without using a string:

```
P = np.matrix([[1., 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]])
```

Comment: Close!  Here is the actual code      P = np.matrix([[1., 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]])  That's very helpful.